# checking if all the entries are "filled" in the matrix in java

Tags: java, matrix, sudoku

I have an assignment where I'm creating a method "allSet" that will go in the class SudokuGrid. The method is supposed to return `true` if all of the boxes are filled and `false` if any of the boxes are yet to be filled/still empty. It is also given in the assignment that an empty box corresponds to the value of 0.

**This is what the class looks like;**

```
public class SudokuGrid {
    private int[][] grid;

    /** Constructd an empty sudoku. */
    public SudokuGrid () {...}

    /** Sets the value value in the box (row, col).
        All arguments are assumed to have a value between 1 and 9. */
    public void put(int row, int col, int value) {...}

    /** Clears the the box (row,col).
        All arguments are assumed to have a value between 1 and 9.  */
    public void clear(int row, int col) {...}

    /** Returns the value in the box (row,col), zero if the box is empty.
        All arguments are assumed to have a value between 1 and 9. */
    public int get(int row, int col) {...}

    /** Determines if the box (row, col) is empty.
        All arguments are assumed to have a value between 1 and 9. */
    public boolean empty(int row, int col) {...} 
}
```

**This is what I've come up with so far;**

```
public boolean allSet(int row, int col, int value) {
        grid[row][col] = value;
        if (value != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

**And the error message I get is;**

```
__Tester__.java:57: error: method allSet in class SudokuGrid cannot be applied to given types;
System.out.println(sg.allSet());
                     ^
  required: int,int,int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

I've been googling and can't understand what that means.. Something with the parameters and I'm not passing anything in?

Thanks for your help in advanced! 
Take care.

Comment: count the numbers of arguments your `allSet` method need to get passed, then count the number of argument you are passing in the error message `sg.allSet()`. You should see that 0 arguments  is not quite 3 and therefor understand your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to read the error message really? It tells you that the required arguments of type int, int and int are not given to the method sg.allset. Provide the corresponding parameters and you should be all fine.

Comment: Method `allSet()` should be declared without any parameters. Inside of it you should iterate over `grid` variable.

Comment: @triplem do you think I would make this amobitious post if I hadn't read the question? I read it and I still don't understand, since java isn't my native tounge and that's why I'm here asking the question, because I read the message and didn't understand it. thanks for you comment anyway